# foreach: %do% needs more processing time than 1-worker %dopar%

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I've prepared a small benchmark to compare what is gain of speed when multiple workers are used for processing.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

f <- function(n){ #just a function that needs some time
  sample(n, 1000000, replace = T)
  sqrt(n)
}

before = Sys.time()
y = foreach(i=1:10000, .combine = c) %do% {
  f(i)
}
after = Sys.time()
after - before # Time difference of 1.764439 mins (105.86634s)


benchmark <- function(n){
  f <- function(n){
    sample(n, 1000000, replace = T)
    sqrt(n)
  }

  cl <- makeCluster(n)
  registerDoParallel(cl)

  before = Sys.time()
  y = foreach(i=1:10000, .combine = c) %dopar% {
    f(i)
  }
  after = Sys.time()

  stopCluster(cl)

  after - before
}

benchmark(1) #Time difference of 1.49561 mins (89.7366s)
benchmark(2) #Time difference of 44.76028 secs
benchmark(3) #Time difference of 32.92803 secs
benchmark(4) #Time difference of 28.984 secs
benchmark(5) #Time difference of 27.46466 secs
benchmark(6) #Time difference of 26.48457 secs
benchmark(7) #Time difference of 26.48769 secs
benchmark(8) #Time difference of 29.07004 secs
```

I've expected `%dopar%` processing time, when only 1 worker is used, to be similar to `%do%` processing time. However `%do%` needed ~16s more seconds. Is it normal?

Comment: I've modified the code. Now it may be rerun fully automatically.

Comment: How are you running this script? Are you using RStudio, for example?

Comment: Yes, I'm using RStudio. I'm running code fragments with CMD + Enter. Yet, IMHO, it shouldn't have any impact on the processing time.

Comment: I asked how you were running your example because I haven't been able to reproduce your results. My `%dopar%` times are slightly longer than my `%do%` times, as expected, even when using RStudio with CMD + Enter.

Comment: I've rerun the code a moment, now 1-worker %dopar% took longer than %do%. It's strange, as i haven't updated any package. 
(Before asking the question I've run my benchmark multiple times, each time results were similar).